# Intuitively why does the central difference method provide us a more accurate value of the derivative of a function than forward/backward difference?

Tags: calculus

From what I have read recently,there are multiple methods to obtain the value of delta y to compute the derivative of a function, delta y/delta x. For as long as I have been learning about derivatives at school, I have only been exposed to the forward difference method, taught as the 'First Principle Method' which was then superseded by the direct usage of equations of common functions, such as trigonometric functions for solving questions

Recently, I learnt about how the central difference method is more accurate. After a lot of pondering of the equation for central difference, I can not quite understand precisely what makes it more accurate.

From what I understand of the forwards/backwards method, delta y is obtained by subtracting a function f(x) by another function f(z) where z = x incremented/decremented by a very small value. This is fairly intuitive because it is quite literally the very definition of delta y or change in a function.

But the central difference method doesn't make sense to me. It is defined as delta y = f(x + h/2) - f(x - h/2)

How is this equal to the change in a function? f(x + h/2) is not the same as f(x) by any means. From the few explanations I saw online, they claim this method is the 'average' of the forwards and backwards methods. I can't quite tell how it is the average of both the methods. Wouldn't the average be something similar to:

delta y = (f(x+h) - f(x-h))/2.

I have also seen another explanation which states that through the Taylor's Series, it is more accurate. For one, the explanation seems more like stating a fact than intuition to me, so I am still left confused. For another, I tried searching up as to what a Taylor's series is, as I have not heard of it before, and I am left with more questions than before.
Thus I am left with the following questions:

(i) I still can't quite tell how this is a change in a function
(ii) How is it the average of both the functions? Why is it more accurate simply because it is the average of both methods?
(iii) Intuitively why does it work?

Comment: The central difference approximation to $f'(x)$ is $f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h) - f(x - h)}{2h}$.

Comment: Why is it 2h? Im assuming its because we added both the forwards and backwards difference method and found the average? Why is it more accurate exactly?

Comment: Have you seen [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#/media/File:Finite_difference_method.svg)? It explains where the centered difference approximation comes from, and perhaps makes it seem visually intuitive that the centered difference approximation would be more accurate.

Comment: @littleO I have indeed seen the picture before. Though it seems more like a statement of a fact than an intuitive reasoning. I am still not able to see why it provides a more accurate result. Sure, the central difference method gives a secant line that more closely approximates the derivative at x , but fundamentally what allows for it to do so?

Comment: The picture at least makes it plausible that the centered difference approximation might be more accurate. It also seems plausible that by averaging the forward and backward difference approximations we could get a more accurate approximation. But to get a more convincing argument, you can use Taylor series to estimate the error in each approximation.

Comment: @littleO As I had stated before, seeing the explanation of how the Taylor's series shows the central diff. method is more accurate seems more like a statement of a fact than intuition. I am also not familiar with it, so I am confused by it. Also why exactly does averaging the forward and backward give us a more accurate approximation?

Comment: Regarding the earlier question “why is it $2h$”: The reason is that we’re computing the slope of the secant line that goes through the points $(x - h, f(x-h))$ and $(x+h, f(x+h))$. The slope is “y minus y over x minus x”, or in other words $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}$. The denominator comes from $x+h - (x-h) = 2h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something called the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).  The exact statement can be found at that Wikipedia link, but the basic gist of it is that if you draw a secant (a bit like a chord in a circle) across two points on a smooth curve, then somewhere in between those two points is a point where the tangent is parallel to that secant.  Like this:

[image]

The theorem doesn't tell you exactly where this blue point is, but it's there somewhere.  Intuitively, though, if the curve changes direction somewhat consistently, you can tell that the blue point will be close to halfway between the two black points, if not necessarily exactly halfway.

That's the intuition between the central difference estimate of the derivative.  Let's take the function $f(x) = x^2$, and try to estimate the derivative at $x = 1$, $f'(1)$.  Suppose we have three choices of how to do this:

- forward: $\frac{f(2)-f(1)}{2-1} = \frac{4-1}{1} = 3$
- backward: $\frac{f(1)-f(0)}{1-0} = \frac{1-0}{1} = 1$
- center: $\frac{f(3/2)-f(1/2)}{(3/2)-(1/2)} = \frac{(9/4)-(1/4)}{1} = 2$

Depicted in a graph, those look like this:

[image]

The forward and backward are shown with dotted black lines, while the center is shown with a solid black line.

Comment: Is there a fundamental or logical reason why the tangent point is close to the halfway point of the secant line?

Comment: After some further reading, I believe I may have gotten some idea. Is it right to say that since the range of the interval in the central diff method is (x-h/2,x+h/2), according to MVT, the derivative at point of tangent line = f(x+h/2) - f(x-h/2) / 2h?

Comment: @Hash: It isn't true in general (though it is true for $y = x^2$), but the idea is that (as I said) if the slope changes kind of consistently, then the parallel tangent will be close to the midpoint of the secant.  In the case of $y = x^2$, the slope doesn't just change "kind of consistently," it changes at a constant rate (in other words, the second derivative is constant), so the two happen to coincide.  But as I say, that isn't exactly true in general.

Comment: Let's suppose you're driving a car around a 90-degree turn, from northward to eastward (say).  At what point will you be pointed exactly halfway in between—that is, northeast?  Intuitively, you would expect it to happen about halfway through the turn.

Comment: In your analogy, the car when it is at the halfway point points in the direction of the tangent line? Also by 'slope changes consistently', are you referring to differentiable functions here that are continuous? While I can see the intuition  for a simple example like this, is there a way to understand it for some polynomial like x^4 + 2x^3 that does not just simply bend 90 degrees?

Comment: There is no easy way to internalize the difference between applying this process to $x^4+2x^3$ and applying it to $x^2$, as I did above. I think hoping to take intuition all the way to the end is not fruitful; the intuition tells you where to go, but sometimes, analysis is needed to get to your final destination. ¶ As far as your other questions go, the car always points in the direction of the tangent line; it's at the halfway point that it points in the direction of the *secant* line. "Changes consistently" means that the "steering" doesn't change wildly in the interval, now left, now right.

Comment: So what would be an example of an inconsistently changing curve/equation? Something like y = sin(99x) that varies rapidly?

Answer (score 3):

One way to explain the accuracy of these various finite-difference approximations is to use Taylor series to estimate the errors in the approximations.

Suppose that $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a smooth function and $x \in \mathbb R$. A Taylor series approximation tells us that
$$
\tag{1} f(x + h) \approx f(x) + f'(x)h + \frac12 f''(x) h^2 + \frac16 f'''(x) h^3
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \approx f'(x) + \underbrace{\frac12 f''(x) h}_{\text{error term}}.
$$
(If $h$ is small then the higher order terms are negligible.)
So the error is proportional to $h$, to a good approximation.

Note also that
$$
\tag{2} f(x-h) \approx f(x) - f'(x) h + \frac12 f''(x) h^2 - \frac16 f'''(x) h^3.
$$
Subtracting (2) from (1) and then dividing both sides by $2h$, we obtain
$$
\frac{f(x + h) - f(x-h)}{2h} \approx f'(x) + \underbrace{\frac{1}{3!} f'''(x) h^2}_{\text{error term}}.
$$
So the error is proportional to $h^2$, to a good approximation.

If $h$ is small then $h^2$ is much smaller than $h$. This explains why the centered difference approximation of $f'(x)$ is more accurate than the forward-difference approximation (at least when $h$ is sufficiently small).

Comment: @Toffomat . Sorry I rejected your edit too quickly but in fact you did the right thing. The last error term should be $\frac{1}{6}f'''(x)h^2$ or $\frac{1}{3!}f'''(x)h^2$ .